# Magento - foreach simple product show name, sku and stock quantity?

Tags: admin, stock

Magento - foreach simple product show name, sku and stock quantity?

Hi, I am trying to accomplish the following. I would like a simple PHP script to show/export: foreach simple product name, sku, stock quantity, stock status

And pref also for configurable products (same but then summed)

I've come accross many good import scripts, but not a small sript to actually show the current stock status. The problem is that we have an employee who just doesnt understand data profiles etc: the problem arises btw when they have to open FTP to look up the file

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533426/daily-inventory-update-through-remote-ftp-file

Question: Any ideas how I can create a small script to show all current stock levels per product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use this

```
<?php

// define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
// umask(0);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::app($mageRunCode,$mageRunType);

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

$data = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
                    ->addFilter('type_id', 'simple')
                    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');

//                    ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())

header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=stockstatus.xls");
// echo "val1\tval2\tval3";
// echo "<html><body>";

// echo "Name\tsku\tis_in_stock\tqty". "\r\n";
echo "sku\tis_in_stock\tqty\t\ttmp_mainprod\ttmp_size". "\r\n";
foreach($data as $product) {
    $stock = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
    $tmp_stock = $product->isAvailable() ? 1 : 0;
    echo $product->getSku() . "\t" .
    $tmp_stock . "\t" .
    $stock . "\t\t" .
    substr($product->getSku(), -2) . "\t" .
    substr($product->getSku(), 0, 6) . "\r\n";
//  $product->getStatus() . "\t" .
// $product->getName() . "\t" .
}

exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work to quickly grab everything you want. There may be a better way to do it.

```
<?php 
// Load Magento
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');


//get the collection filter the simple products & join the cataloginventory/stock_item table
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('sku')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple')->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left'
) ;
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
<?php 
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$product->getSku()."</td><td> ".(int)$product->getQty()."</td></tr>";
};




?>
</table>
</body></html>
```